# Controller not being called

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Im new to angular and trying to get my first controller working inside an ASP.net MVC application.  In my main view, there is a scripts section like so

```
@section Scripts{
<script src="~/js/home-index.js"></script>
 }
```

The javascript file simply has this

```
function homeIndexController() {
   alert("we are here");
}
```

Then in the view, I have this

```
   <div class="main-content" data-ng-controller="homeIndexController">
```

Using fiddler, I see the javascript file is included at the bottom of the page, but the alert is never displayed.  What could I be missing here?  Its as if the page cant see the script inside that file?

I looked at the request with IE developer console and I see an 
**error with Angular**

> Argument `homeIndexController` is not a function, got undefined

**[update]**
I finally realized I was creating my controller the way things were done prior to version 1.3
http://wildermuth.com/2014/11/11/Angular_1_3_and_Breaking_Change_for_Controllers

Once I updated the way I was creating the controller, I got my super-duper alert to show up.

Comment: I am kind of new too, but where you defined your module ? as far as I know controller will not work without module anymore

Comment: Are you using `ng-app` and including Angular as well?  What does your full HTML output look like?

Comment: You need to include the ng-app directive to initialize angular. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Comment: Yes, I have 
<html lang="en" data-ng-app=""> in my layout template.   However, the angular error seems to indicate it cant see my controller function

Comment: @bitshift can you post up your whole html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a controller, you have to do:

```
angular.module('yourApp').controller('homeIndexController', function () {

});
```

This tells angular "Hey, I have a controller called 'homeIndexController', feel free to use it somewhere."

Comment: thanks,  it turns out I was following along with an example that was done prior to Angular version 1.3, which changed the way controllers were created/referenced